# How to generate new workbooks with vba button intact

Tags: vba

I have a worksheet that has a macro (as a button) that generates a separate worksheet w/ some analysis on it. Is it possible to generate a new workbook with the old workbook's VBA intact and with the new workbook's button referring to the new workbook's VBA?

Comment: `SaveCopyAs` should do that

Comment: also make sure that your code does not reference the workbook by name